# What's the preferred way to change the sort order of content items in a promotion?

Tags: smarttarget

In SmartTarget 2014 SP1, content items in a promotion (in case it returns more than one) are sorted by FredHopper by 'Natural Order'. Sometimes I would like to change this sort order, for example to sort news articles or events by date. Is this possible, and if so, what would be the preferred way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You choose the field you wish to order on, as well as ascending/descending preference, on the "Filtering and Ordering" tab of a Promotion.

Note that for a field to show up there, it needs to be a *live attribute* within Fredhopper ('added to the navigation index').

For more information, see the following pages in the documentation:

- [Filtering and ordering content](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-09B2E4B8-AA87-4B45-9EF8-FBC85C0BA16E)
- [Adding attributes to the navigation index](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-EA86B8AA-6904-40AD-AF3A-AA7BC0ED1CD0)